# NodeJS nimble module series function does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, flow-control

What is the problem with this code, it should run all 3 functions, but it runs only the first one:

```
var flow = require('nimble');
function first() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('First');
    }, 500);
}

function second() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Second');
    }, 500);
}

function last() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Last');
    }, 500);
}

flow.series([first, second, last]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nimble requires each function to run in the series to invoke a callback function that tells Nimble to move on to the next task in the series.  The example is right there on the [Nimble homepage](http://caolan.github.io/nimble/).

Here's the updated version of you code.

```
var flow = require('nimble');
function first(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('First');

    callback();
  }, 500);
}

function second(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Second');

    callback();
  }, 500);
}

function last(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Last');

    callback();
  }, 500);
}

flow.series([first, second, last]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nimble is made to accept callback functions in series or in parrallal but you need to give them in array.

```js
// first we need to install nimble with 'npm install nimble'
//there is a another flow control tool called nimble
//we need to add it using require.is small codebase

var flow = require('nimble');

//in nimble we will pass each set of function as a element of array
//hence we are including them in [] 

flow.series([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('I execute first');
            callback();
        },1000);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('I execute second');
            callback();
        },2000);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('I execute third');
            callback();
        },3000);
    },
]);
```

I think it will help you to understand it more